# What is wrong with my regex Pattern to find recurring cycles in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, regex-negation

I want to match any string that has a recurring cycle. Like in this data:

```
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333 / 1 digit cycle(3)
1666666666666666666666666666666666666666 / 1 digit cycle(6)
1428571428571428571428571428571428571428 / 6 digit cycle(142857)
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 / 1 digit cycle(1)
0909090909090909090909090909090909090909 / 2 digit cycle(09)
0834522467546323545411673445234655345222 / no cycle
0769230769230769230769230769230769230769 / 6 digit cycle(769230)
0714285714285714285714285714285714285714 / 6 digit cycle(714285)
0666666666666666666666666666666666666666 / 1 digit cycle(6)
```

The pattern I have tried is `"([0-9]+?)\1+"` which works well in other languages (like VB or text editors). I have stored these strings inside a list named `values`. So here is my code:

```
import re

#stuff to get values
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+?)\1+")
for value in values:
    matchObj = pattern.search(value)
    print(matchObj) #-> None
    matchObj = pattern.findall(value)
    print(matchObj) #-> []
```

What am I doing wrong? Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an r prefix:

```
r"([0-9]+?)\1+"
```

That will make the backslash a literal backslash instead of escaping the 1.

Comment: thx. works like a charm. Although I saw that `r` as prefix in the examples of http://docs.python.org/library/re.html, I couldn't find the explanation for this

Comment: @Rafael T - Be sure to also check out the: [Python Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html "An excellent regex reference even for non-Python folks")

Comment: @RafaelT @NedBatchelder How to match all recurring substrings ? `abababqweqweqwe` -> `aba`, `qwe` ?