# Java regex to find pattern of digits

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have a sequence of numbers

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

As you can see there is a cycle here:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Now I am trying to make a regex expression to match a pattern. The pattern can be half the length of the sequence or 2 numbers long. This is what I have so far

```
Pattern cycle = Pattern.compile("((\\d+\\s)+(\\d+\\s))\\1");
```

I am given a string of numbers delimited by spaces. I am trying to use capture groups but not understanding it. Any help?

Comment: I don't think this problem can be easily solved with regex-es. Also what do you expect as an output for `1 2 3 4 1 2 3`

Comment: generally, if you have to "remember" something in pattern recognition, then regex is usually not the best choice. you'd be better of using a context-free automata

Comment: @izomorphius it can, don't forget the power of capturing groups ;)

Comment: As fge pointed out, regex implementations in most languages (including Java's) are somewhat more powerful than standard regular expressions, and can probably solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
(\d(?:\s+\d)+)\s+\1
```

This will match two or more digits separated by spaces, capture it and look for what is captured right after another space character:

```
(            # begin capturing group
    \d       # a digit, followed by
    (?:      # begin non capturing group
        \s+  # one or more space characters, followed by
        \d   # a digit
    )+       # end non capturing group, repeated once or more,
)            # end capturing group `\1`, followed by
\s+          # one or more spaces, followed by
\1           # the exact content of the first captured group
```

Note: it assumes that the spacing is *exactly the same* in the repetition!

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to understand the question better. Is your problem similar to detecting a cycle/pattern in a given string ?

Something similar to this pattern ?

```
 "([0-9]+?)\1+"
```

this pattern tries to capture a repeating pattern in a given stream of numbers.

Similar to the one discussed in this question [What is wrong with my regex Pattern to find recurring cycles in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640840/what-is-wrong-with-my-regex-pattern-to-find-recurring-cycles-in-python).