# Python Regex to find reccuring patterns or binary strings

Tags: python

I've seen that the below works for decimal numbers/string: (in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640840/what-is-wrong-with-my-regex-pattern-to-find-recurring-cycles-in-python))

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([0-9]+?)\1+")
```

but it doesn't seem to work at binary strings. 
EDIT: Adding an example:

> For string **1110111011** it should return the pattern **1110**

So I would like to get the longest repeated pattern. 
Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Comment: what are you expecting the output for the given binary number to be?

Comment: I don't see the recurring pattern in that string.  Did you mean to add a `10` to the end of it?

Comment: There are limitations in Python's regex library related to variable length look-aheads.  I do not believe you can use `([0-9]+?)\1`.  I'll see if I can locate the reference.

Comment: @JoranBeasley the recurring pattern on string 1110111011 is 1110.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows what you mean by "doesn't seem to work".  Spell out what you *want* it to do.  This is what it *does*:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"([0-9]+?)\1+")
>>> print pattern.search("1110111011").group()
111
```

And that's exactly what the regexp asked it to do:  it found the shortest repeating pattern at the leftmost position where one occurs, which happens to be 3 repetitions of the initial digit `1`.  If you want the longest repeated pattern at the leftmost position at which one occurs, take `?` out of the regexp:

```
>>> print re.search(r"([0-9]+)\1+", "1110111011").group()
11101110
```

If you want something else, you'll need to say what that is ;-)

### Finding the longest overall

As noted, a regexp search finds the leftmost position at which the pattern matches, and that's all.  So consider this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([01]+)\1+")
print(pattern.search("11010").group())
```

That does *not* find "1010".  The leftmost position at which the pattern matches is at the first character, where "1" is repeated.  So that prints "11".

Applying `re.findall()` can't help in this case, because the true longest match *overlaps* the "11" initially found.  `findall()` only returns non-overlapping matches.

Overcoming this is pretty excruciating ;-)  It's possible to do it with a single regexp, via abusing a "positive lookahead assertion":

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?=(([01]+)\2+))")
for match in pattern.finditer("11010"):
    print(match.group(1), "at {}:{}".format(*match.span(1)))
```

That displays:

```
11 at 0:2
1010 at 1:5
```

But I don't know of a way to make a regexp find *only* the longest global match, and would be surprised if such a way exists.

Comment: +1 for Nobody knows what you mean by "doesn't seem to work". Spell out what you want it to do.

Comment: Sorry for being vague guys, I have updated the post hope it is better now. What I basically want is a regex that will recognize recurring patterns in binary strings, i.e. it should return 1110 when string=1110111011

Comment: @timpeters This is exactly what I was looking for, the longest repeated pattern. Thank you very much

Comment: Hope it helps, but it's probably *not* what you want then:  note the "at the leftmost position at which one occurs" qualification. Play with it ;-)